# where to get Tattvasiddhi Śāstra

Tags: reference-request

Anyone knows where I can get my hands on Tattvasiddhi Śāstra by Harivarman, also known as Satyasiddhi Śāstra also known as Prodbhūtopadeśa also known as Chengshi lun. Paper or electronic format is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's available for download here at Scribd.com](http://www.scribd.com/mobile/doc/104775752/Satyasiddhisastra-of-Harivarman).

But it looks like one must buy a subscription in order to read their books.

Comment: Thank you. The quality of the scan is not so good but it is readable.

Comment: No problem:) It's a difficult book to find. Apparently it cannot be bought anymore and no libraries seemed to have a copy of it. I hope you can get through it in its current form.